# set md-datepicker in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a table that is created using `ng-repeat`. Within that table I have an `md-datepicker`. Some of the rows will have a date set for in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I would like to pre-set the datepicker to that value if it exists. How should I go about doing that? Here's the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="y in rides | orderBy : 'id'">
    <td >{{y.Student}}</td>
    <td>{{y.Instructor}}</td>
    <td><md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="dateChange(myDate, $index)"></md-datepicker></td>
</tr>
```

I tried adding `ng-init="myDate = y.Date"` to my repeat but this didn't do the trick.

Comment: You want to avoid using a single model in `ngRepeat`, otherwise changing one date will change all of them

Comment: I'm using the `ng-change` to make a call to my server and update it. Then the route is refreshed and the new data is shown. So I'm not terribly concerned about changing all of them because it will just reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `ng-model = "y.Date"`

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="y.Date" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="dateChange(myDate, $index)"></md-datepicker>
```

Edited

create filter to convert string to date

```
.filter('formatDate', function() {
    return function(obj) {
      debugger;
        obj.Date = new Date(obj.Date);
        return obj;
    }
})
```

call that filter from ng init to convert string to date

```
<tr ng-repeat="y in rides | orderBy : 'id'" ng-init=" y | formatDate ">
   <td>{{y.id}}</td>
   <td>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="y.Date" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="dateChange(myDate, $index)"></md-datepicker>
   </td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/c72tEXx2q1XYnCgmfyoE?p=preview)

Comment: If I do that, my ng-change function won't be able get the new date?

Comment: pass the `y.Date` as param in ng change

Comment: you don't need to pass `y.Date`, just remove `ng-change`

Comment: the call to `ng-change` is working create. But when I get my table with `ng-repeat` it's not displaying the date. Would it have anything to do with how mysql is storing the date? The date from my server is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: using `ng-model="y.Date"` I get the following erorr `The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string` Is there anyway to cast y.date to a Date instance before seeing it to `ng-model`?

Comment: try to use in your query `date_format(start_date,"%m/%d/%Y") as start_date_format`

Comment: added the filter, still getting the same error about a `date instance`.

Comment: post your `rides` array

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I'd have to filter out a lot of private data. But here is the date portion of the JSON returned from the server. `Date\":\"2017-03-21\`

Comment: Finally got a chance to give this another try. Got it working now. Had to add `if (obj.rideDate == null){
   return;
  }` in the filter to take care of the empty date. But works like a charm now. Thanks for the help everyone!